# Sum with filter based on string Power BI

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, measure

I have this [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLpui.png).

I want to create a measure that will only work with the Products containing "HDD" in their name (first, second and fifth product in that case).

It's working with that formula : `HDDProduct= CALCULATE(COUNT([Product]),FILTER(ALL([Product]),SEARCH("HDD",[Product],1,0)))`

It only count the number of product with HDD in their name. But if I want a sum of the prices of those products for example, it won't work. I can only use COUNT.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for sum you have to create another measure, below are my resolution to your question

for count
**HDDProduct_count = CALCULATE(COUNT([Product]),FILTER(Product_table,SEARCH("HDD",[Product],1,0)))**

for price sum
**HDDProduct_Price_sum = CALCULATE(SUM(Product_table[Price]),FILTER(Product_table,SEARCH("HDD",[Product],1,0)))**

note: please check the data type of price column to integer data type

[image: screenshot of my result in power bi]

[download pbix file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CY2WexPpk7KsNGMCDM5Nv3IMthDswUmp)

Comment: Perfect ! Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot.